# Jenkins: prevent unnecessary dependent jobs to be executed

Tags: jenkins, dependencies

Imagine I have two jobs A and B in Jenkins, which will monitor and build project A and project B. Since project B relies on project A, I add a trigger for project B when project A is built successfully. 
It is working fine in most cases, but when I checked in codes to both project A and project B, project B will have a failed build due to dependency to project A newly added code, and then a successful build after project A finishes. It does really annoying. Is there any way to prevent project B building before project A is built in this case?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Project B Configuration. Click on *Advanced...* at *Advanced Project Options*. There select *Block build when upstream project is building*. This will prevent building B while A is building.